# Automatically restarting Perfmon Data Collector Sets

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, perfmon

I have a number of User Defined Data Collector Sets running on a Windows 2008R2 server, collecting perfmon stats from various servers.

Whenever there is a network interruption, or a server rebooted (at worst, when the server which is running all these DCSs is rebooted), I have to manually restart some or all of the  Data Collector Sets.

Is there a way to configure them to automatically restart, or otherwise be more resilient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scott,

Does this link help? http://zachbonham.blogspot.com/2007/10/logman.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the solution at the link below to do this via Task Scheduler.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/jeff_stokes/archive/2011/11/16/how-to-sustain-your-data-collector-set-through-a-reboot.aspx

Comment: As a heads-up, there's a known-issue with some Windows Server 2019 Builds that breaks Task Scheduler's ability to start Data Collector Sets at startup. Details AND work-arounds found here: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/user-defined-dcs-doesnt-run-as-scheduled